# How can I use same model folder in Zend Framework 3 for all modules

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3

I have to configure model classes in every module and for every controller for table gateway.

Any way to use the same model folder and configuration for all modules?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. A good question explains the problem, things you tried (code!) and the problem you're stuck with and what you expected instead of the problem.

Comment: Models are only classes you call by their namespace. Create a model module and put all your model there (even though this is not a best practice).